# Is Defense Damage Reduction?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Some enemy Monsters have Defense. If you don't do more damage than their Defense, each attack only deals the minimum amount of damage (1). If you deal enough damage to overcome their Defense, is Defense subtracted from the damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, monster defense reduces all damage.**

Except defense-ignoring damage, obviously. This is most easily tested on monsters with very high defense. If you hit such a monster just barely hard enough (ideally such that only one of your cards beats its defense) and watch the damage numbers that appear on the monster (the actual damage dealt) you'll see a much lower damage value than the card's raw damage (the number that appears on the card when you attack).